# Different available sizes for Float and Integer in python

Tags: python, rsa, exponentiation

I've read some similar posts and the solution which you sugest is Decimal module. But my problem isn't that my code can't count it. I mean once it can and once not. Im interested in RSA and learning encryption and decryption private keys there is simple code:

```
p=53 #secret
q=59 #secret
n=p*q
k=2 #secret
print(n)
PHI=(p-1)*(q-1) #secret
print(PHI) #secret
#choose a small public exponent, "e" must be odd, have no common divisors with phi (n)
e=3
d=(k*PHI+1)/3 #secret
print(d) #secret
# secret message is 89
c=(89**e)%n
print(c)
x=(c**d)
print(x)
x=x%n
print(x)
"""x=1394**2011
print(x)"""
```

There is no problem with counting ((89^3) mod n) and there is no problem with last equation (as a comment) 1394^2011= i have number with 6324 digits, but when i try use x=(c^d) mod n i have :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RSA.py", line 77, in <module>
    x=(c**d)
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

Comment: The Decimal module is not a good choice for RSA. It provides no benefits over a plain python integer in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e` is an `int`, and so `89**e` can be arbitrarily large (though I would use `pow(89, e, n)` so that you don't have to compute the large intermediate value `89**e` first).

`d`, however, is a `float`, and `c**d` will also be a float. A `float` cannot grow arbitrarily large, hence the error.

Since `d` is supposed to be an `int`, use floored division.

```
d = (k*PHI + 1) // 3
```

Comment: One stupid slash, thanks im new and i didnt know that floats cannot be so big